# Using functions from directive controller within link function of same directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how directive controllers work, from what I understand they are used as a sort of API to be exposed to other directives & controllers. I am trying to get the controller and link function to communicate internally.

For example I would like to be able to set a variable via the controller function and then use it in the link function:

```
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);

app.directive('coolDirective', function () {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            this.sayHi = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.myVar = "yo"
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.myVar);
        }   
    }
});
```

How can I access myVar or sayHi within the link function? Or have I just missed the point completely?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Both controller's $scope (defined in the controller, not in the `sayHi` function) and link `scope` are the same. Setting something in the controller will be usable from the link or viceversa.

The problem you have is that `sayHi` is a function that is never fired so `myVar` is never set.

Since `sayHi` is not in the scope, you need a reference to the controller and to do it, you can add a fourth parameter like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {}
```

Then you could do a `ctrl.sayHi()` (But again, those params of `sayHi` belongs to the controller function.)

If you ever need to require another controller and still wanting to use its own directive, then you will need to require it too. So if this `coolDirective` needs to access to the controller of `notCoolAtAll` you could do:

```
require: ['coolDirective', 'notCoolAtAll']
```

That will do the trick. The `link` function will receive then an array of controllers as the fourth param and in this case the first element will be `coolDirective` ctrl and the second one the `notCoolAtAll` one.

Here is a little example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JXahWE43H3biouygmnOX?p=preview

Comment: perfect thanks heaps, makes much more sense to me now!

Comment: hello ... if I add `console.log( scope.name ) ; ` within your link function, it returns `undefined` ... how can I access MainCtrl's `.name` property ... thanks ...  (see forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/STVVT5Vj9tkV9t0LFxKu?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect answer. Not able to figure out how to do until I see your answer :)

Comment: Is there any way to access the "element" variable from link function in the controller??

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your code above, it would look something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);

app.directive('coolDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            // bind myVar property to scope
            $scope.myVar = 'yo';
            // bind sayHi method to scope
            $scope.sayHi = sayHi;
            // abstracting out the sayHi function
            function sayHi() {
                console.log($scope.myVar);
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            // execute the sayHi function from link
            scope.sayHi(); // "yo" in console
        }
    };
});
```

Good Luck.