# Run function in controller from directive's link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive:

```
.directive('directive', [ function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        value: '=value'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        $document.bind('click', function() {
            ...call clickDocument() function
        });
    },
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: 'item.html',
    controller: 'Item as item'
  };
}])
```

And controller for this directive:

```
.controller('Item', [function Item () {

   this.clickDocument() = function() {
      console.log('click the document')
   }
}])
```

I want to run `clickDocument()` from the controller on document click event.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Nick take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864294/using-functions-from-directive-controller-within-link-function-of-same-directive I think it explains what you are looking for.

Comment: @M.Octavio, thank you, I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the controller in the link injectables.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {}
```